# QGIS extremely slow after adding a key map

Tags: qgis, atlas, qgis-atlas

I am currently working on an atlas export project and I needed to add a key map.
I created a new map theme for keymap and added open topo map only and created a 2nd map in the layout.

But the problem is that the moment I added the key map project became too slow it takes around 2 3 minutes before atlas moves to next area.

Is there any other thing I need to change while adding the key map?